# What is the daily reputation cap and how can I hit it?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

I've found some questions and those two badges "Epic" and "Legendary" regarding the "daily reputation cap". What is it and how can I hit it?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The maximum amount of reputation you can earn *in one day* from upvotes and approved suggested edits is 200.  Any *upvotes* you receive after reaching that number no longer award any points.

You can still earn rep beyond the cap by winning a bounty, accepting an answer, or having one of your answers accepted. Reputation earned from these activities before reaching the cap does not count towards the cap. Downvotes still count against you after reaching the cap, but when this causes your score to drop below the daily cap amount, the points lost can be reclaimed from new upvotes. (Previous votes will not fill in the difference.)

If any votes to your posts are invalidated by the system (e.g. by the serial voting script), your reputation will be recalculated as if the invalidated votes never happened. For example, if a serial upvoter caused you to hit the cap, and you later earned legitimate upvotes that didn't give you any reputation, you will earn the reputation from those legitimate votes once the script reverses the serial votes.

The reputation cap is per site, so reaching the reputation cap on one site doesn't influence reputation that can be earned on other sites.

Comment: I think this has been changed a bit, but don't have the reference handy.

Comment: If you can still earn rep how is that a cap?

Comment: @I3arnon Well, you won't any longer receive reputation for simple upvotes. Otherwise, once you asked a clever question, your reputation would immediately go through the roof ;) This is sort of a cool-down. And the reputation you still can get should keep you encouraged in continuing to help others.

Comment: @Patrick this is totally common sense, same as badges for example. But guess no harm adding it.

Comment: when someone reaches the daily reputation count and then gains another vote on one of their other answers, do they get that reputation the next day?

Comment: No, they do not get that reputation. They get credit for the vote in the score on that answer, but they don't earn any new reputation points. The vote may still be useful to their reputation score if at some point in the feature a user or vote is rolled back and their rep is recalculated.

Comment: @iDebug you totally changed the meaning of the answer. Please do NOT do that. If you think something is wrong, ask first. If the author is away and not responding for a day or two, try asking in chat. Another option, if you think the answer is wrong, is to post your own answer.

Comment: @Sha in the current state, it seems to sound wrong

Comment: @ShadowWizard So why you approved the later suggestion from Ano? It still "totally changes" the meaning of the answer.

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ three months later I don't really remember and don't have the link to your rejected edit handy. Guess Ano explained better, so made me re-think. Review isn't something that should take long for the reviewer: if it takes too long to understand and decide if the edit is good or bad, it usually means it's bad.

Comment: @ShadowWizard there's no review. You rolled it back and told me don't do so. See the rev history of this answer.

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ you're right, sorry. Anyway, your edit summary was just "clarify", without any source of proof, you just changed X to Y in the answer. Ano referred to actual source (links in your answer), so the change can be verified.

Comment: @ShadowWizard OK, I'll write clearer edit summary later.

Comment: Can you replace points spent on a bounty even if you've already reached the cap?  E.g. I reach the cap, then create a bounty for 200 points -- can I then earn 200 additional points to replace the ones spent on the bounty?

Comment: @snydergd No, you can't.

Answer (score 11):

As time goes by, the above answer is no longer 100% correct. Specifically,

> Reputation earned from these activities (accepting/accepted/bounty) before reaching the cap does still count towards the cap.

Has been changed. What's in effect now is

> Reputation earned from these activities before reaching the cap **no longer counts** towards the cap.

Here's [Jeff Atwood's blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/03/21/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/) explaining the change as well as [another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43832/350567) claiming it.

Comment: So edit the answer... that's what editing is for.

Comment: @Catija My edit [was rejected by Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it/303991#comment988209_32161). See Revision 10 and 11 of that answer.

Comment: Subsequently the change was made to the accepted answer.