# Does acquiring only 200 reps in a day from only votes count toward Epic/Legendary?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-badges, reputation-audit

Let's say that yesterday's numbers according to the reputation audit is:

```
days represented D
rep cap was reached on R days
rep cap was exceeded on E days
```

I earned only and exactly 200 reputation points yesterday through only upvotes, no bonuses. Some upvotes were subject to the cap and scored [0] in the audit.

Today's numbers are:

```
days represented D+1
rep cap was reached on R+1 days
rep cap was exceeded on E days
```

Note that the number for *exceeded* stayed the same. This seems to "make sense", of course, because 200 does not exceed the rep cap, it merely reaches it.

Perhaps it's my fault not to work harder for that one acceptance, but I'm just wondering if someone can confirm for me that as far as {Legendary} is concerned, yesterday was wasted.

#### Related questions

- [How is it possible to exceed the rep cap without reaching it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49402/how-is-it-possible-to-exceed-the-rep-cap-without-reaching-it)

> ***Jeff Atwood says***: did you reach 200 rep from PURE UPVOTES? That's *reached*. Did you reach 200 or more rep from upvotes + accepts? That's *exceeded*. Neither calculation includes bounties. [current Epic/Legendary badge calculation] is based on *exceeded*, though the description is mildly incorrect and would lead you to believe it is based on *reached*.

So the way I understood the above quote is the following:

- 19 upvotes, 1 acceptance = 205: *exceeded* but not *reached*
- 20 upvotes, 0 acceptance = 200; *reached* (*exceeded???*)
- 21 upvotes, 0 acceptance = 200; *reached* (*exceeded???*)
- {Legendary} looks only at *exceeded*

So my question is essentially asking for a confirmation on the latter two bullet points: does scoring 200 and only 200 from upvotes count as *exceeded* or not, and does it matter whether or not you have [0]-scoring capped votes?

---

#### Addendum

If it's true that you also need at least one acceptance, what happens if later that acceptance is retracted? Is that day wasted as well as far as {Legendary} is concerned?

And if so, what would be a better strategy to guarantee that no day is wasted and every day counts? Does the (+2) from accepting a question you ask count toward *exceeding*?

Comment: I confirm: >200 (and not ">=200") is required to make the "rep cap was exceeded" increment. You need one answer accepted at least. If retracted later, your "rep cap was exceeded" will decrement. And 150 "rep cap was exceeded" is not enough. I am at 152 for a week now. No badge.

Comment: @VonC: thanks for the confirmation. I wish I had known this in advance =( One day wasted =( Oh well =( What's the deal with a week and no badge, though? Is `{Legendary}` computation THAT infrequent, or is there a bug? What are you missing?

Comment: I don't know. I am only at 90 for the "rep cap was reached" part though. May be some kind of combination is needed. Or like you say, the computation for this badge is *not* every day.

Answer (score 7):

Some time since this post was written back in 2010, the rules changed. As explained in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285155/347902), scoring 200 exactly is now enough (and can be even if you paid reputation to downvote).

Comment: ...moreover, the information is now displayed as `rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on X days; earned at least 200 reputation on Y days`.

Answer (score 3):

I've just checked my rep report and it says that I have exceeded the cap on 20 days, which is the number used for the Epic & Legendary badges. However, looking for days where I have got 200 or more there are 21.

The discrepancy is one day where I got exactly 200:

-- 2009-04-22 rep +200 = 1128

While getting 200 seems to trigger the Mortarboard, it *seems* to count it as strictly greater than 200 for the Epic and Legendary badges.

**NOTE** I'm not complaining, as the number of days that I exceed the rep cap is growing at a such a slow rate "missing" one or two isn't really going to make much difference.

Comment: a/ I confirm the "strictly greater than" b/ even if you had the 150 days required for Legendary badge, nothing would happen right now. For both points, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/is-150-rep-cap-exceeded-alone-enough-for-legendary-badge

Comment: I can actually confirm this, too, since I recently had a strict 200 day. That said, I still did earn my Mortarboards at exactly 200, so I'm not quite sure how it works for actually earning the badge - it's entirely possible that the formula on the reputation audit is > while the actual system cares about >=.

Comment: Where do I find this 'rep report'?

Comment: @AndrewMao - http://stackoverflow.com/reputation