# Why did I get the Epic badge?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, daily-reputation-badges

There must be something wrong with my understanding of the rules for 'Epic' or with the reputation audit output.

I was just notified that I have received the Epic badge (on SO) but the bottom end of my reputation page looks like:

```
** total rep 32580 :)

days represented 489
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 25 days
rep cap was exceeded on 33 days
```

I don't see how I could even have come close to 50 days.

Some additional info:

- no bounties collected
- only 2 days with exactly 200 rep
- when I count the `rep + xxx = yyyy` lines I get  >= 200 on 36 days

Comment: Interesting. That being said, 50 days is a lot. That must be why only 99 people have it.

Comment: I'm also under 50 with both values and got my epic badge a while ago. Maybe the epic badge counts the days on which you got 200 or more reputation from upvotes or accepts.

Comment: @sepp That's what "exceeded" means.

Comment: My totals are 10 and 21 and the total days where I have > 200 rep is 21. So I would expect your total to be at 33 - still some way off the target for "Epic".

Comment: @NullUserException: I was under the impression that "exceeded" means "more than 200", not "200 or more".

Comment: @sepp Exceeded means "200 or more" as far as I can tell.

Comment: What? 25+33 > 50 I don't see the problem. The 25 days are not (all) part of the 33. If you exceed by getting a bounty, you have not reached the cap with upvotes "only".

Comment: @Ladybug: If you get 200 from upvotes and then another 15 from an accept, you have both exceed the cap and reached it from upvotes only.

Comment: @Ladybug It's my understanding that "reached" is a subset of "exceeded." (as weird as it sounds)

Comment: @Ladybug - the total number > 200 is 33. The 25 comes from days when you get would have got > 200 points from votes if there were no cap

Comment: @sepp2k - that's right. I've got a day when I got exactly 200 and it doesn't count to the "exceeded" total - though it was the day I got the "Mortarboard" badge ;)

Comment: @sepp: Yes, but I am talking about getting 100 with upvotes and then 200 with a bounty. It only counts to the last figure, not the first. So his max. number of days can be greater than 33.

Comment: @NullUserException: Neither is a subset of the other. You can get reached without exceeded (e.g. exactly 20 votes, no acceptance) and you can get exceeded without reached (e.g. 20 acceptances, no votes).

Comment: @Jon I thought exceeded meant `>= 200` rather than `> 200`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current thinking is that the badge calc is *incorrectly* including rep from deleted posts.

Comment: Ok, that would figure.

Comment: @Henk this is the issue - a fix will be pushed tonight... but we're not going to revoke your badge, since you're close to getting it and were so honest :)

Comment: @Jarrod: Ok, thx. But I now think I might have reached/exceeded it 50 times, it's just that the record doesn't show that anymore. It's a matter of definition.

Comment: @Henk - Good point actually. If you exceed the repcap only to have a question deleted on you is it fair to retrospectively say you didn't?

Comment: not sure that this is actually fixed - I just got the Epic badge even though /reputation shows that I only exceeded on 47 days.

Comment: [Just happened to me, too.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278674/deserved-or-undeserved-epic-badge-earning)

Answer (score 5):

As I said in my comment I also have recently gotten the Epic badge, so I did some analysis on my rep report.

I have had more than 200 points 46 times. This is the number shown for "rep cap was exceeded". I have had 200 points or more exactly 50 times. So as I speculated in my comment, the badge calculation counts how often your rep was `>= 200` while the report counts `rep > 200`.

Comment: Good catch. It would be nice if the report and badge calculations matched.

Comment: Woah, tricky...

Comment: Still, my own count for >= 200 turns up 36, best i can make of it.

Comment: This `>=` vs `> 200` issue was discussed here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56620/does-acquiring-only-200-reps-in-a-day-from-only-votes-count-toward-epic-legendary ; it looks like neither number is a "subset" of the other, you can increase one independently of the other.