# Reputation graph / page inaccuracy

Tags: support, reputation-graph

Today I got the *Epic* badge. It should be awarded for [earning 200 or more rep on **50 days**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88465/mortarboard-badges-being-awarded-as-a-result-of-bounties-after-recalc/88526#88526).

It did not expect to get it. Why?

When I open https://stackoverflow.com/reputation I see the rep calculations. And at the bottom it says:

> earned at least 200 reputation on **38 days**

Well, I don't bother too much, because there seems to be a bug in the badge calculation which [counts deleted posts reputation too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61091/why-did-i-get-the-epic-badge/61173#61173).

But when I open my rep graph I see this:

[image: Rep graph]

Yes, I counted them manually: On **42 days** I hit 200 rep or more in that graph.

**So why the difference between the rep graph and the */reputation* page?**

I dug a little deeper and noticed one day (2012-04-26, <sub>there must be 3 others</sub>). According to the */reputation* page I earned **178 rep**:

```
 2  10328039 (10)
 2  10328039 (10)
 2  10328562 (10)
 2  10329163 (10)
 2  10328562 (10)
 2  10328562 (10)
 1  10328562 (15)
 2  10329054 (10)
 1  10329054 (15)
 2  10330906 (10)
 2  10330906 (10)
 3  10330906 (-2)
 2  10331207 (10)
 2  10330323 (10)
 2  10331207 (10)
 2  10336737 (10)
 2  10336737 (10)
 2  10330323 (10)
-- 2012-04-26 rep +178  = 8751
```

But according to the rep graph I earned **203 rep**. It contains **1 answer more**: *[SQL, Android SQLITE Join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10340613/575376)*

[image: Rep graph answers]

Seems like the question got unaccepted another day and an upvote undone.

Looks like either the rep graph or the */reputation* page is inaccurate. Is that a bug or just *by-design*?

## Edit

I found another issue:

```
 2    163179 (10)
 2    163179 (10)
 2    163257 (10)
 2    163257 (10)
 2    163257 (10)
 2    163257 (10)
 2    163257 (10)
 2    163257 (10)
 2    163257 (10)
 2    163262 (10)
 2    163257 (10)
 2    163257 (10)
 2    163257 (10)
 2    163262 (10)
 2    163257 (10)
 2    163262 (10)
 2    163257 (10)
 2    163257 (10)
 2    163257 (10)
 3    163262 (-2)
 2    163257 (10)
 2    163262 [2]
 2    163257 [0]
 2    163257 [0]
 2    163257 [0]
 2    163257 [0]
 3    163281 [-1]
 2    163257 [1]
 2    163262 [0]
 2    163262 [0]
 2    163262 [0]
 2    163257 [0]
 2    163257 [0]
 2    163257 [0]
 2    163262 [0]
 2    163257 [0]
 2    163257 [0]
 2    163257 [0]
-- 2013-01-10 rep +200  = 3973
```

Shows 200 rep on Jan, 10th in my rep statistics. But the graph shows

[image: Graph]

**290 points** earned with upvotes! That is totally wrong!

Comment: There was a [recent change to the badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181103) that makes downvotes you cast and receive not count towards the totals for the badge. Do you have some days that are very close, hold the downvotes?

Comment: Not really. I have a few removed posts that keep me from 200 rep some days.

Comment: Looks like you want the badge to be taken away... `:-/`

Comment: Congrats on the badge! I'm at 13/50 but working on Generalist (17/20)

Comment: You have show removed posts checked, look at January 21st and you can see.  /reputation *never* included deleted content where the profile shows it added and then removed *if* you opt into doing so.