# No answers bounty text misleading

Tags: feature-request, bounties

[A bounty of mine ended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182559/reputation-graph-page-inaccuracy) with no answers.

But still the text of the bounty message says

> This question had a bounty worth +50 reputation from juergen d that ended yesterday; **you must award this bounty as soon as possible**

Please remove the highlighted text if the question has no answers. I can't award it.

Comment: Not really a duplicate. The user is asking for support since (s)he is confused. I report a bug/feature request.

Comment: True but see the accepted answer: "this can certainly be seen as a bug". Then the OP in comment: " perhaps the wording should be conditional on whether the bounty can actually be awarded?" and in response: "Either that or be changed to encompass both cases". Isn't this exactly what you want as well?

Comment: Get somebody to answer before the grace period expires. Too late :(

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: True, but I fear being closed in this constellation that will never be concerned being implemented. Generally I have the feeling a question closed is like denying the request no matter how many upvotes the original post has. But that's another story... :)

Comment: @DanielFischer: I could still award it...

Comment: Oh, I saw "The grace period has ended" and assumed you couldn't anymore. Anyway, I don't have an answer, so couldn't try to grab the bounty.

Comment: I have reopened this question since the feature request is legit and not a duplicate of the aforementioned.

Answer (score 7):

The system should not send a message instructing me to award an answer if there is none (this is what happens nowadays).  This is incomplete coding development which requires additional coding.

I recommend that a filter for such solutions be created with an automated message to the effect of:

> Your bounty period has expired, yet your question received no answers. The bounty points you offered are not refundable. You may offer a new bounty, if you wish.