# If no answers are offered in a bounty, automatic message should not be “you must award answer”

Tags: feature-request, bug, bounties

I posted a bounty on [OSMDroid android app zoom in without changing tiles, is it possible?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/192828/115) which, even after 1 week with bounty, received no answers (I have found a solution and will post it eventually).

IMO, the system should not send a message instructing me to award an answer if there is none (this is what happens nowadays).

I recommend that a filter for such solutions be created with an automated message to the effect of "Your bounty period has expired yet your question received no answers.  The bounty points you offered are not refundable.  You may offer a new bounty, if you wish."

NOTE: before any trigger happy flagger goes about declaring this to be a [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186023/197031), please pay attention that it is a BUG REPORT / FEATURE REQUEST , not a whining "where did my bounty points go" and that the above question never received an answer (it was incorrectly marked as a duplicate also).

Comment: I am still in doubt whether to close this question as a duplicate or not, since it actually is. Whether it received an answer or not is not that important. I have reopened the linked question since that wasn't really a duplicate, so it can receive answers now too.

Comment: the point is not to get answers, but to correct a bug.  this is a current problem that did not receive attention.  by closing my question you are being bureaucratically correct, yet counterproductive.  i respectfully disagree because this question goes way beyond the first one's scope (i read it and included it reference to it in my quaestion).  but have it your way, @patrick hofman.  as long as something gets done.

Comment: I agree they have to improve this. I really do. Thanks for bringing it under our attention :)

Comment: ok, tks.  please look at my answer to original question http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279807/197031

Comment: I already did, and edited to make the text stand out more.

Comment: and why no vote (up OR down)?  not that i am begging for points, i dont care for them.  but rather to give said answer some credit and peer attention?

Comment: I was still thinking whether I could agree on the text or not. I will vote when I know. :)

Comment: why no answer of your own then?  row, man, row.