# Epic and Legendary - hit the cap, or just reach 200?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

To get the Epic and Legendary badges, do you just have to simply reach 200 rep (say, 15 checkmarks and zero upvotes) on 50 or 150 days, or do you have to cap out on that number of days.  The text of these badges:

> Earned at least 200 reputation on 50 days.
>
> Earned at least 200 reputation on 150 days.

implies the former, but I remember distinctly these badges requiring users to hit the cap.  Am I just crazy?

Jeff's comment in [his SQL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58192/155403) implies you have to hit the cap, but the actual code implies just the rep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *do not* have to hit the rep cap, only reach +200 rep by any means.

For example, for the Epic badge [The Big List Of All The Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) states (with my added emphasis):

> #### Epic
>
> - silver; awarded once; same family as Mortarboard (bronze), Legendary (gold)
> - Earned more than 200 reputation on 50 days
>
>   - ***Reputation source can be any vote type, upvotes, accepted answers, bounties...any net increase from votes (not association) totaling >= 200.***
>   - Each "day" lasts from midnight UTC to immediately before midnight, UTC; days are **not** counted in local time
> - Sources: [Is 150 "rep cap exceeded" *alone* enough for Legendary badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/is-150-rep-cap-exceeded-alone-enough-for-legendary-badge), which includes [the actual query that produces the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/is-150-rep-cap-exceeded-alone-enough-for-legendary-badge/58192#58192) in an answer by Jeff, [How is it possible to exceed the rep cap without reaching it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49402/how-is-it-possible-to-exceed-the-rep-cap-without-reaching-it/49405#49405), which features more human-readable comments by Jeff, Nick Craver's edit to the definition of Mortarboard, below, and research explained at [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78867/how-is-it-possible-to-reach-the-rep-cap-without-exceeding-it/82796#82796).

Answer (score 3):

You have to reach at least 200 reputation at that day (**it's not necessary to reach the cap**)<sup>`[1]`</sup>.

The counts for capping and counting are different:

```
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 41 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 58 days
```

I have already earned the `Epic` badge, although my `rep cap reach` count is only 41.

<sub>*`[1]` I have checked my [reputation audit](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), and counted all occurrences of over 200 reputation (through the JS console), using:*</sub>

```
document.body.textContent.match(/rep \+([2-9]\d\d)/g).length; //Prints 58
```

Comment: Adn you have the Epic Badge.  I'd say that about seals it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cap the reputation in 50 and 150 days. They do not have to be consecutive.

Comment: Then surely the text of those badges needs to be changed?  15 accepts (alone) would give you 225 rep, but would not count as a day toward those badges.