# Spurious “rep cap reached” in reputation audit

Tags: bug, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-audit

My reputation audit on Academia ends on:

```
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 1 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 0 days
```

While I am aware that [this is theoretically possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78867/255554), this does not apply to me: My highest reputation on one day was 147 according to the audit as well as my reputation tab (including removed posts). I also never received large chunks of negative reputation by downvotes, bounties or similar.

Comment: Was any content *deleted*?

Comment: Go to your [reputation tab](http://academia.stackexchange.com/users/7734/wrzlprmft?tab=reputation&sort=time) and check the *show removed posts* at the bottom of the page. Then look through your reputation and see if you hit 200 *with removed posts shown*.

Comment: You don't need to have lost large chunks of reputation, just 1 is enough to move you from 200 to 199.

Comment: @Servy: the highest *visible* one-day reputation score is 147. What *is* surprising is that I don't see a mortarboard badge, so if a deletion took place it took place before the badge batch process ran to award it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Including removed posts does not change this. I am also not aware of any major reputation shifts due to deletions.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: then I am out of ideas for now; lets see if a moderator or dev chimes in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters might be a case of a post deleted after more than 60 days with score of 3 or higher. This cause the reputation to be preserved, hence no reputation event in the profile.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: it should be easy to check; just add upp all reputation and if 53+ seems missing you could have a viable hypothesis.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I just did that and only 1 reputation is missing. Also, shouldn’t this at least show up in the audit?