# Current rules for Epic/Legendary badge concerning rep loss after hitting the cap

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

When I reach 200 or more points in a day and have my daily rep counter (including negative events) on >=200 for at least a moment, does that day count towards badge progress, even if I end the day at 23:59 UTC with less than 200 points (e.g. due to later downvotes or spent bounties)?

All Meta posts I could find about this topic were from 2010 or earlier and I am not sure whether those old rules still apply, I believe they changed.

Answer (score 8):

The moment you've earned at least 200 reputation from anything (excluding the association bonus) then that day counts towards the badge - the reputation cap has absolutely nothing to do with the badge. Downvotes do not count against you for a day; the badge script ignores all negative events for the day when determining your eligibility. The badge progress *tracker* is sometimes temporarily incorrect because it only looks at *upvotes* (absolutely nothing else) when tracking your progress for the current day, but will eventually update when it recalculates your number of days again. As an example, a +200 bounty award will instantly hit the mark for that day with no votes whatsoever, but will show as a progress of 0 during that day and increment later on.

However, it's also important to realize that simply hitting the mark for the day is not permanent. You can still lose the day if votes for the day get retracted later on, because a user removes their upvote, the serial scripts kills a bunch of them, or a chunk of that reputation is lost due to the post being deleted. The number of days you've hit the cap is recalculated *every time* the badge script checks. There is not an imaginary number behind the scenes counting how many times you've simply hit the number.

Comment: So let's say I get 19 upvotes and an accept on one day, but spend a 50 bounty or cast or receive a few downvotes early in the morning, so that the daily rep counter in my reputation notification inbox never actually reaches 200. Would that day still count towards badge progress, because summing up only the positive events, ignoring the negative ones, would theoretically have brought me beyond 200?