# What happens when someone earns more than 200 daily reputation but the total earned that day is less than that due to users being removed?

Tags: support, reputation, badges, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

Last January 27th in the [Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/) site some users were removed, and I lost 210 reputation points due to their upvotes being also removed. Nonetheless, that same day I earned 205 reputation points due to my questions and answers. So the total reputation earned that day was -5 points.

Nonetheless, the reputation points being lost was something I could not help. I once earned those points, and the only reason to lost those points is the users being removed, not the users changing their minds and thinking that my answers now do not deserve those points. But the +205 points was something I really earned.

I sincerely do not mind having earned more or less rep points that day (I really do not want this to sound as a tantrum), but I was wondering, does a day like that count for the Mortarboard, Epic and Legendary badges? If not, why? My point is as I said before: you once earned the lost points and could not help losing them, but you do really earned the rest of the points.

Comment: However, on the current way the badges are tracked, if you first hit the cap, you have yet another day over 200, so it will count towards Epic and Legendary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As animuson explains [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285157/152859):

> it's also important to realize that simply hitting the mark for the day is not permanent. **You can still lose the day if votes for the day** get retracted later on... The number of days you've hit the cap **is recalculated every time the badge script checks**...

When a user is removed, the votes they cast are also removed. So yes, that day won't count towards the Mortarboard, Epic, and Legendary badges. Note you won't lose existing badge due to  this.

Fair? Not really. But it also helps against gaming the system: suppose someone creates a voting ring (one person with bunch of fake accounts voting each other) and earns 200+ rep daily by this. When moderators find this and delete the fake accounts, the main account shouldn't get any badges.

Comment: and typically, if a moderator finds out all what is left of the ring will be a smoking pile of ashes.... so I think the badges (which I assume could be removed anyway manually) are the minor problem here.

Comment: @Derpy true, but knowing in advance those badges aren't likely to be given might make some of those think twice.

Comment: If they didn't  "think it twice" knowing in advance that their accounts would be gone... I doubt the idea of a missing badge would really motivate them to behave.

Comment: @Derpy some do it just for the badges. I think. Not sure though.