# 'User was removed' and '+200 reputation' limit

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit, deleted-accounts

I've lost 10 reputation because of [*user was removed*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471/208082) for the first time today and I'm just wondering, why there 10 points don't affect [+200 daily reputation limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/208082)?

To describe what I'm talking about just a bit more, I've got 4 accepted answers today, so I'm able to receive 260 reputation points today: 60 from accepted answers and 200 from upvotes. However, because of these -10 points I earned only 250 reputation, no matter how many more upvotes I receive.

Comment: Ask Jon skeet..

Comment: Just hit the same issue when removing one of my answers and lost 30 reputation with it. I can confirm that I cannot that earn that back for today with upvotes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The loss of reputation affects the rep cap of the day the upvote was given, not on the day the upvote was removed.

If you had exceeded the rep cap by more than 10 rep on the day you got the upvote from the now removed user then you would not have lost any rep; the other rep from that day would have compensated for the lost rep.

The fact that you lost the 10 points today doesn't mean that you can now earn an extra 10 rep beyond the rep cap today.

Comment: OK, Seems logic. Thank's for the answer! I'm gonna mark it accepted asap.

Comment: Is this still the case? My reputation today stops at 155 with 5 upvotes that are not counted anymore. (60 reps lost because of user removed).

Comment: @zoechi What you're describing is entirely consistent with this answer.  The user being removed results in your reputation being calculated as if those votes were never cast, not as if you were losing 60 rep as of today.  You can't earn 260 rep today in order to negate the loss of rep from the deleted votes, as that would exceed the rep cap for the day.

Comment: @Servy " you had exceeded the rep cap by more than 10 rep on the day you got the upvote from the now removed user then you would not have lost any rep;" So it could be that there were more than 6 upvotes from this user but only these who were removed from days where I didn't exceed the rep cap are removed today?

Comment: @zoechi Yes, it's also possible that they involved actions not counted in the rep cap, like acceptances.

Comment: @Servy thanks a lot for clarification!