# Reword explanation for Epic badge

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-badges

I had no idea what "*Hit the daily reputation cap on 50 days*" meant. I had to come here [for an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33189/im-confused-about-the-epic-badge). Can you kindly reword it to something like "*Hit the daily reputation cap 50 times*".

[**clarification**] The way it's currently worded, it sounds like the cap was hit after 50 days or ...!? That's the confusing bit, "**on 50 days**". The fact that the linked question was asked (and got 7 votes) is a good indicator that the message isn't really clear. There shouldn't really be a need to come to meta to know what a simple description means?

[**note**] Those who seem to understand English more than the rest of us [seem to agree](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10123/achieved-on-50-days-vs-achieved-50-times).

Comment: I hit it because it owed me money.

Comment: Shameless plug: this is why we have [the list of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399)!

Comment: The fact that the linked question got 7 votes doesn't suggest that it's the "on 50 days" which is confusing though - I suspect that's why *this* question hasn't received the same support.

Answer (score 5):

Is the difference between "days" and "times" *really* the confusing bit? I would have thought not knowing what the daily reputation cap was in the first place would be the cause of confusion.

Comment: Failing that, I would think that "hit" would be the issue, since the `/reputation` page lists "times reached" and "times exceeded."

Answer (score 1):

Just add the term to the FAQ and make the "daily reputation cap" part of that text with a link to this new entry or to another place where the user can find a good answer to that. For example, the [What is the daily reputation cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it) question here on Meta.

From my own experience, it took me more than one intent to learn what the **daily reputation cap** is.

I mean, I (not an English speaker) understand that there is something I have to "hit" 50 times to earn that badge, and that this thing has something to do with the rep, but I have no idea what it was until I Googled it and found it.