# Hit the daily reputation cap on 50 days and get the Epic

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, stack-overflow, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I'm confused about the “epic” badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33189/im-confused-about-the-epic-badge)

Hi all,

I am a member for a year but I did not understand some badges

One of them is Epic user, can any one suggest me how to earn this badges ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can also see more details about the requirements for every badge [in this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).