# What is the new daily reputation cap?

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit

What is the daily reputation cap after the [reputation scoring changes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/)? I've noticed that since these changes occurred I still get reputation from upvotes (not accepted answers) even after the 200 daily reputation points. Is this normal?

Comment: Looking at your [reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov?tab=reputation), it appears that you are only getting reputation from upvotes *before* the 200 cap, not after, and only getting repuation from accepts after the cap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you had an accepted answer or bounty awarded to you in the day *at any time* (that's the change) it doesn't count towards the cap.

So if you got an accepted answer when you were at 100, you can get up until 215 from upvotes.

Before you could only pass the 200 mark if you got an accepted answer when you were already at 200.

Comment: ahhh, ok. Now I get it. 200 in upvotes and unlimited in accepted answers. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: yes, and bounties, and the +2 when you accept an answer

Comment: So it's no longer an advantage to live in a time zone where you tend to answer questions in the latter part of the day as defined by UTC (where I live, the day ends at 6 PM on standard time, 7 PM on DST).