# Daily rep exceeded

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I have exceeded the daily rep limit. Why is this possible, not that I am complaining. :)

If I look at today, in SO I see 218, a couple up voted answers, accepted answer and a down vote.

Can someone please explain.

Comment: By "today" you mean you actually clicked the "today", right?

Comment: Yes, under my account.

Comment: You can also check this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43830/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got [228 with 4 accepted answers and 1 downvote](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=107862). Actually, you need another 32 points to even *hit* the rep limit, now that [the +15 from accepted answers is immune](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/the-great-reputation-recalc-begins/).

Comment: That is what I was missing, I did not know that accepted answers were immune. Is there a way to see your actual applied rep, or do you just exclude the accepted answer items? Thanks

Comment: @durilai - there's always the rep report: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: @Durilai, there use to be a reputation break-down page during the Great Recalc, but it seems to have disappeared. edit: @Marc, oh there it is.

Comment: That has the accepted answers also, so just a manual exclusion. More curious than anything. Thanks