# Why upvotes does not counted?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Upvotes to my answers @ SO are frozen for couple of hours - is it an intended behavior?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You've hit your reputation cap for today. Congrats.

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason you might not get more reputation from more upvotes is if you had already hit the rep cap for the day, which I believe is 200 (not counting rep for bounties and accepts)