# Strange behaviour on an old answer

Tags: bug, daily-reputation-limit, featured-tag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the daily reputation cap and how can I hit it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it)
>   [How do I read the history of my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/how-do-i-read-the-history-of-my-reputation)

On July the 13th on [user:69339] history, under Stack Overflow, it can be seen 128 upvotes from 8H38 to 23H46 that is to say an average of an upvote every 7 minutes but only 20 upvotes with points on a answer done in february 2009. The question has been closed as not constructive, Protected by community. What is the meaning of all that

[image]

...

[image]

Comment: It's the [repcap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Comment: OK for the 200 points, but 128 upvote for an answer existing till 2009 ? Iso distributed in the time every 5-7 minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 200 repcap is obviously a dupe of many questions. So I'll skip that.

---

As for why that user got a huge burst of votes in a such a short amount of time:

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573623/powershell-vs-unix-shells-on-the-windows-platform) was linked from Hacker News: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4238696

That brought in a large number of votes (and views) in a very short amount of time. This is quite common and can happen to any question new or old.

---

However, the question itself is apparently "not constructive". So it accumulated a bunch of poor answers over the past few years. When it was finally linked on Hacker News, it brought enough attention to the question to get it closed and get all the bad answers deleted by moderators.

Because of the large number of moderator deleted answers, the question was automatically protected by the community user.