# Missing Reputation Badge

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

My answer in this post
[What is ImmutableArray in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318688/what-is-immutablearray-in-c-sharp/17318810#17318810)  receives 4 votes.
**Answer Badges** rules of **SO** says:

- **Nice Answer**: Answer score of 10 or more
- **Good Answer**: Answer score of 25 or more

According to rules,shouldn't i get those badges? Not sure,whether i miss any calculation.Can anyone point this?

Comment: I think the rules should clarify what "score" means, since it is somewhat ambiguous: [Clarify what "score" means in badge descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188260/clarify-what-score-means-in-badge-descriptions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the badge for *total votes*, not for the reputation you earned.

The score of a post is the balance of upvotes and downvotes. Once the vote total (upvotes minus downvotes) goes over 10 you earn a badge.

For example, a post with 10 upvotes and one downvote has a score of 9 and won't be eligible for a badge until it gets another upvote.

4 up votes and 0 downvotes means your answer has a score of 4. The 40 reputation you earned is not the answer score. The two values are separate (reputation is [capped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it) for example, but your answer can still gain score by being upvoted).

Comment: 4 upvotes means 40 points,isn't it?I received points,not the badges..

Comment: @ridoy: No, that is reputation. Not votes.

Comment: But rules says not for votes,it says about scores 25 or more.

Comment: Yes, but score is not the same thing as reputation. Score is the balance of upvotes and downvotes. Reputation is.. reputation, not score.

Comment: A little bit confusing this system,can you clarify about score and reputation points?

Comment: @ridoy "score" in this context is the net number of up-votes, NOT the reputation. Reputation is different than just a count, for example you get +10 rep for 1 up-vote on an answer, +5 for 1 up-vote on a question, -2 for a down-vote on either, and -1 when you down-vote an answer. [Many more details here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Yes clear now,but SO should change the rule as Good Answer: Answer received upvote 25 or more. Does SO contains any edit suggestion or bug submission system to inform something like it?

Comment: @ridoy: No, it is not 25 upvotes or more. It is a *score of 25*, where score is the number upvotes minus the number of downvotes.  A post with 25 upvotes and 3 downvotes does **not** give you a Good Answer badge.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well, what if it gets 25 up-votes on day 1, then gets 3 down-votes on day 2? I think the badge will already have been issued and doesn't get taken away.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, can you give my 2nd question answer?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: regular badges are never revoked, but your **next badge** won't be awarded. On day one it reached 25 votes, you get the badge. The next day to it gets downvotes, you are up one badge. The *next time you get 25 votes on a question* you do not earn a badge that day to make up for that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters interesting, I wasn't aware of that. Is it documented anywhere? And if then the first question gets three more up-votes, do you get a badge for the second question at that time?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: see the [badges faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work): *However, if the criteria for a badge no longer exist — e.g. the post it was awarded for is deleted — the next award of that badge is negated. When badges are awarded, the system checks to see how many you're supposed to have, and only awards new badges when the number of badges you're supposed to have is greater than the number of badges you have. (As of 2012-01-16 this doesn't apply anymore for some of the badges)*. Followed by an explicit answer badge example.

Comment: Does SO contains any edit suggestion or bug submission system to inform something like it?

Answer (score 3):

"Score" relates to votes, not points of reputation earned from votes.

"Score" is a bit ambiguous, to be fair.

Comment: Yes it is confusing,normally 1 upvote results 10 rep points,if score relates votes,then Answer score of 25 or more is very much confusing whether it says about votes or points!!

Answer (score 1):

The wording is confusing.  The word "score" should be replaced,

I recommend rewording both to "Answer up-voted ## times or more".

Actually, "up-voting" is a bad use since "score" is the sum of up and down votes.

It does need to be something other than the innocuous "score".