# Clear rules on answer badges

Tags: discussion, feature-request

According to the description of Answer Badges on SO:

- **Nice Answer**: Answer score of 10 or more
- **Good Answer**: Answer score of 25 or more

From [Missing Reputation Badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188252/missing-reputation-badge) post, I came to know that

> "score" in this context is the net number of up-votes, NOT the
>   reputation

and

> It is a score of 25, where score is the number upvotes minus the
>   number of downvotes.

So isn't the word **score** confusing in this context? Clearly that rule should define it as “**upvote minus downvotes**” or have the definition of what the word "score" means beside it.