# Guru badge description is misleading and should be changed

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, badge-description

Is it just me or is the [Guru](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/18/guru) badge description a bit misleading?

> Accepted answer and score of 40 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

At first read it seemed that a person need to accept an answer of score 40.

I would suggest to update the description to (for example):

> Provided an accepted answer with score of at least 40. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

Comment: And this still contains the ambiguous "score" reference - is that 4 up-votes or 40? Related discussions: [Clarify what "score" means in badge descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188260/clarify-what-score-means-in-badge-descriptions) and [Missing Reputation Badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188252/missing-reputation-badge)

Comment: And the description also does not include the information that this badge is (currently) **not** awarded for questions that you have asked and accepted yourself.