# Forgotten reputation point?

Tags: support, bug, reputation

Today, I answered to many questions and I won points with up votes or validated answers. But, when I go in the [reputation tab of my user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1932751/lucas-willems?tab=reputation), I can see some up votes are not counted.

For example, I answered to a question and, until now, my answer has been validated and got 7 up votes. So I should win, if I'm not wrong, 7x10 + 15 = 85 points. But, if I look the reputation tab, I see I only won 15 points.

So I would like to know why points are not counted ? The problem comes, probably, from me, but I don't know from where.

Comment: Congratulations on hitting the repcap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the daily reputation cap and how can I hit it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it). See also: [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)

Comment: @Mysticial And will I won the reputation which is not counted ?

Comment: @LucasWillems Correct.

Comment: Ok. I was afraid.