# User is serially voting for me.. What to do?

Tags: support, voting, serial-voting

Let me explain. There is a user with just 20 rep voting on every answer/comment I post on Stack Overflow. In my reputation overview I can see I'm not earning any rep anymore after just a few votes by this user, but my concern of getting banned/losing my rep because of this user made me post this question.

Is there any way to block a user or something? Hope someone has some good advice in this matter.

Comment: How do you know who is voting on your answers?

Comment: By 'spamming' do you mean that they're leaving spam links on your posts? Or, if it's around serial up/downvotes then it's likely their votes will be automatically removed overnight anyway if it's triggered suspicious voting patterns. That won't impact any genuine votes you've have from other people.

Comment: Serial upvoting (strangely) is something people do, you won't automatically be blamed for it

Comment: @RoryAlsop because I'm not seeing any +rep points for many upvotes in my overview, has to be the same person.

Comment: Joran - you can't tell who they are though. So why do you think it is a particular user with 20 rep?

Comment: This is different than the usual case, not a dupe.

Comment: @RoryAlsop because the user made comments too ;)

Comment: fair enough :-)

Comment: lol, but got my answer thanks! Sorry for the duplicate, was searching for the wrong words..

Comment: From what I see, it should be pretty obvious who this person is. May I suggest you talk to them and ask them not to vote for you in this manner? Also, they really shouldn't be copying answers that you have left. The system will probably reverse these votes, but this kind of targeted voting really shouldn't continue.

Comment: Thank for your comment @BradLarson, I indeed saw the copied answers.. Did flag as spam! Kinda weird, maybe they want to get rep in a quick way or something.. Thanks again.

Comment: Just a note to anyone that sees copied answers that flagging as "spam" is not appropriate -- probably the better thing to do is to flag as "other" and explain the situation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to do anything.

Serial voting (receiving a large number of upvotes or downvotes from the same user in a short period of time) is automatically reversed after some time. You will likely see your reputation drop in the near future when these votes are reversed, but other than that, there should be no negative consequences for you.

You stopped receiving reputation, not because the system thought there was anything suspicious going on, but because you reached the [daily reputation cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it).