# Jon Skeet rep-capping at <200 pts, but then later getting points for upvotes up to 200?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-history

I know about the [daily reputation cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it) and according to the answer in that question:

> Any upvotes you receive **after** earning 200 reputation from upvotes for the day no longer award any points.

But look at [Jon Skeet's reputation changes today](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=time).

[image: jon skeet rep changes]

From the screenshot, he stopped getting reputation for 10 upvotes (100 rep) and 1 accept (15 rep). i.e., He stopped getting reputation for upvotes after he had 115 rep.

But if you look at his reputation changes later, he still got 80 rep for upvotes.

Why did he stop getting reputation after 115 rep instead of 200 until later?

Comment: Your screenshot only shows 1/6549801th of this rep history today. Add it up, there 20 upvotes that counted for +200.

Comment: There's a "`19 hours ago reversal Serial upvoting reversed`" in there.  Could he have hit the cap but then fallen below it again when the serial voting was reversed?  I'd expect that to re-run history though, rather than counting later votes.

Comment: @Mysticial I thought reputation are ordered according to how they are recieved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

His total is being summarized by question.

This appears in the list:

> +80  8 hours ago     upvote  java.util.Date class with different
>   approach for same date gives different output

His most recent vote was eight hours ago, which he didn't receive points for, but he received 80 points from it before he reached the Rep Cap.

This happened with several other questions as well.

**You can prove this to yourself by voting on one his answers and seeing it move to the top of the list.** But there's no indication that multiple votes took place.

Comment: That logic wouldn't work for the couple of entries in the list like "`+10 4 hours ago upvote How do I return to an older version of our code in Subversion?`" that he got well after rep-capping, but without multiple votes at different times.

Comment: @blahdiblah You can't see how many votes he got. It just shows the last vote and the total number of Rep.

Comment: Ahh, so you think the time is based on the most recent upvote received whether it provided points or not.  That could certainly explain the gaps (which are common on other days as well).