# What exactly is the process to earn Hat Trick hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

I am changing my hat on profile for three different days wearing different hats. I also earned hats on Thursday, Friday and Sunday. Still I have not got this hat.

Comment: List of hats available, and how to earn each one http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Reputation cap is common term and you seem to mis-understand its meaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The description of the "Hat Trick" for Winter Bash 2015, says **hit the reputation cap on three different days**

So you need to earn reputation from your post/edit on three different days. I.e., minimum [200 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32160/312043) on three separate days.

Screenshot for your reference:

> [image: Hat Trick hat]

Comment: More difficult to do than I thought, as it turns out ...

Comment: the reputation part is tricky