# Why is my reputation not getting counted?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Can any one help me out? I am receiving upvotes on my answers and questions but reputation is not getting added.

Please have a look at the below imags:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there any limitation that I am not aware of?

Comment: No, stop! Don't do that!

Comment: @ʇolɐǝzǝɥʇqoq There is a 200 daily rep limit; any more rep gained in one day will not be counted.

Comment: @quartata Really sorry, didn't know that XD

Comment: @Ratan Don't go ask in other communities!!! Come back!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is a rep cap.**

On this day, you received [over 200 reputation on Salesforce Stack Exchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/18731/). There is a cap at 200 rep *excluding* bounties and accepted answers. After you hit this, you cannot get any more reputation from upvotes. See also [What is the daily reputation cap and how can I hit it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it?lq=1).

The reason you received more than 200 rep is because one of your answers was accepted (+15) and you accepted an answer (+2).

Comment: Damn, beat me to it.

Comment: @quartata Great minds think alike?

Comment: @HDE226868 Yes This is the reason.. Really Thanks.

Comment: @HDE226868 is there any way to get my those reputation ?

Comment: @Ratan bounties and the +15 for accepted answer are not capped, so you can gain more than 200 by those. But not from upvotes.

Comment: And great minds think alike, but greater minds think faster. /cc @quartata :-D

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes I am getting accepted +15 but there is no way to get all the upvotes reputation also ?

Comment: @Ratan no, no way. You'll probably find [this discussion and its answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059/revisiting-the-rep-cap-yes-again) interesting. In a nutshell, the 200 rep cap from upvotes is to "keep the game fair" to most people.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ok Thanks for make this clear