# Why is rep-cap count not increased even it seems I hit rep-cap?

Tags: bug, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Today, on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27264/a-j?tab=reputation), it seems that I hit rep-cap as reputation from upvotes is no longer countable. I also have an unaccept, which caused loss of 15 rep.

However, my rep-cap count, i.e. Epic badge progress count is not increased. It is same as 23 as before. Before this, whenever I hit rep-cap, a count is increased, but today it didn't happen.

What is the reason behind this? I even cleared cache etc and checked on different browsers.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about how the progresses work, but it would probably make sense to assume they work like the scripts that award badges, so I would guess the rarer badges need some wait before any change in the progress is visible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your activity profile:

[image]

You earned 185. The criteria for Epic is ["earn 200 daily reputation 50 times"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/badges/42/epic). 185 is not 200, and your Epic counter is not increased.

The things that may be confusing are:

- **The Epic criteria is *not* "hit the rep cap 50 times", it's "earn 200 daily points 50 times".**
- Also, the rep cap is *not* a cap on total reputation earned, it's *only* a cap on [rep earned from votes and suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it). Accept/unaccept does not affect the rep cap, so, unlike that -2 from the downvote, that -15 from the unaccept *doesn't* allow you to earn more points for upvotes (on the flip side, you can earn *more* than 200 points in a day if you get enough accepted answers to push you over 200).

So you hit your vote/edit reputation cap. You got 200 points for that. You lost 15 for the unaccept. So while you hit your rep cap, you did not earn 200 points that day, you earned 185.

Comment: Ah! So I lose around 100 rep, though it doesn't matter, and yet I didn't make any progress towards Epic badge. This may also explain why I hit rep cap at 145 when I offered 50 bounty and the count was still not increased.