# Reputation increases beyond daily reputation limit if a downvoted answer gets deleted

Tags: bug, reputation, down-votes, daily-reputation-limit

I've seen this happening several times:

- I downvote an answer (and thereby my reputation decreases by one point);
- I reach the daily reputation limit;
- the answer that I downvoted gets deleted (or I cancel my downvote);
- my reputation increases by one point (it shouldn't; this is not one of the exceptions mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32161/402142));
- many hours later, my reputation decreases by one point, but my list of recent achievements doesn't mention that.

So, in the end my reputation is what it should be and therefore this is not a serious issue. But it still looks like a bug: I simply should *not* get that extra reputation point.

Comment: "*I simply should not get that extra reputation point.*" are you sure? You aren't *gaining* a point - you simple *never lose it*. Reputation is (mostly) a function of all votes on your posts and other sources. A downvote removes a reputation point from you but undoing it (either by you or deletion) makes the lost rep just not count. So, you haven't gained 201 rep this day, you've still only earned 200 in total.

Comment: Does the rep cap, cap the rep that can be earned in a day from upvotes, or allow more rep to be earned if some is used up by downvote?

Comment: @VLAZ, that is true, but not the entire truth. If I am rep capped, and downvote, my repcap is reduced to 199, and any upvote my posts get gains 1 rep, locking into the rep cap again. Removing a downvote by post deletion gives back the 1 rep, effectively raising the rep cap by 1 point.

Comment: @IanRingrose Depends. When you reach the cap, get an upvote (which wouldn't count) and then downvote something, then you would lose rep and the previously ignored upvote wouldn't add the missing +1. But when you get another upvote after your downvote you would gain the +1 again (if I remember correctly).

Comment: @Luuklag Yes, but it shouldn't do that for long. The rep is recalculated at some time (maybe only once a day) and the additional 1 point should then be removed again.

Comment: @Luuklag I understand what you mean but perhaps there is a deeper question here - is the repcap 200 positive rep or is it 200 rep change total. What do I mean - on Monday, you get an upvote for +10. On Wednesday, you get 20 upvotes for +200 rep and you hit the cap. Later that day, the upvoter from Monday removes their upvote - you lose 10 rep. Today, you're at a +190. Can you now gain rep or not? Even more interesting - the Monday upvoter who retracted the vote, upvotes the same answer again. Do you (re-?)gain 10 rep or not?

Comment: @Luuklag also, what if you get 150 rep, the upvote from Monday is removed, you get 50 more rep, then the upvote from Monday is added again. Do you end up with 200 rep total and *losing* 10 rep from a different day, or do you (sort of) gain 210 rep from this day (where 10 comes from a different day).