# Query regarding an user's reputation cap detail

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Today I see an [user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164403/fr%c3%a9d%c3%a9ric-hamidi?tab=reputation)'s reputation tab, where the user received +201 reputation from upvote.

Regarding reputation cap, as I [aware](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32161/312043) we can still earn rep beyond the cap by winning a bounty, accepting an answer, or having one of your answers accepted.

But the user already received 20 upvotes and what was the possible way for the last +1 reputation?

Is that, any of the answer downvoted by the user was deleted or something else? I want to understand the scenario behind the +1 reputation.

> [image: Reputation cap]

Comment: Just guessing: maybe the user did downvote somewhere (which might not show up in that view), but could be compensated by the next upvote?

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. Possible way, when seeing the user's Votes cast section in the [Activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164403/fr%c3%a9d%c3%a9ric-hamidi?tab=topactivity), 13 votes are there for the week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see is the result of a downvote given on an answer. That is a private reputation event and it doesn't show up except for the user themselves; the downvote costs one reputation which is compensated by an upvote; a public event which *does* show up for everybody.

You can see a similar thing happening in my reputation history on December 4th, 2019. For you all, there's a peculiar +1:

[image]

but when I view my own profile, I can see it's compensating a -1:

[image]

<sub>(There's something else going on here with the daily totals, the 203 is 'right' but the 204 is not: [Wrong daily reputation total on profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341951/295232))</sub>

Comment: Dec 4th example is more clear. Thanks.